# pass error from inner stored procedure db2

Tags: stored-procedures, exception, db2, procedure, procedural-programming

I am new to db2 and got stuck in a problem which shouldn't be tricky.

I have a procedure try_a which calls another procedure try_b

in both the procedures i have declared exit handler for sql exception. 
Suppose in try_b divide by zero error is encountered then that is returned using SIGNAL.

When try_a (exit handler written)calls try_b then on case of divide by zero error in try_b ,sql exception of inner block is not shown.

Can you please help how can this be achieved.

I don't have a sample code now. Will try to put that tomorrow.

Comment: ... Is it at all possible to rewrite `try_b` to **not** generate a divide-by-zero error?  That particular one usually indicates that you haven't sufficiently guarded against it in the first place.  What should the "result" be in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `SIGNAL` in the inner stored procedure, the condition that is raised is the user-defined type, not the original condition that cause the inner condition handler to be invoked. It has its own SQLCODE, SQLSTATE, and message. You could use the `RESIGNAL` statement to raise the same condition.

Alternatively, you could log error messages to a temporary table or a file in each condition handler.

Comment: I tried using continue handler and store message in declare global temporary table but didn't work. resignal needs the error to be specified but there could be any error, i don't want to specify the same. will cgtt work??

Comment: "_resignal needs the error to be specified_" -- no it does not. "_but didn't work_" -- seriously? It works for me.